# How to find the real target of the event?

Tags: javascript, events, target

The code:

```
<html><head><script>
function onChange()
{ var e = window.event;
}
</script></head><body>
<input type=hidden id='txt' onchange='onChange()'>
<input type='button' onclick="document.getElementById('txt')['onchange']();">
</body></html>
```

The problem:

All properties of the event object - currentTarget, srcElement, target, toElement - lead to the button. I need to get the reference to the hidden input, assuming that I do not know it's name or ID - in the real code the event handler may belong to several hidden inputs.

Comment: `onchange='onChange(this)'`, then get the input as the parameter to `onChange` as in `function onChange(input)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use something like the following:

```
<input type=hidden id='txt' onchange='onChange(this)'>
```

And then in your onChange you can grab this

```
function onChange(elem){
   //do something with elem
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do

```
onclick="onChange.bind(this,document.getElementById('txt'))();"
```

Now, in the event function `arguments[0]` refers to the element with id=`txt`

Comment: Did you test this? You are trying to call `bind` on the string value of the `onchange` attribute, which will not work at all.

Comment: Oh my bad I figured it would call the function...fixed